# HaxeDevelop Openfl releasing to Neko .exe opens terminal console

Tags: haxe, openfl, neko

... which shows & lists all the `trace();` , `boolean` and `int` changes... How do I disable this terminal console from opening when I open the `.exe` generated through neko?

Help **sincerely** appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to singmajesty's (OpenFL author) answer [here](http://community.openfl.org/t/removing-background-console-on-neko-target/657/4) regarding this issue, it's currently not possible:

> This is currently the way Neko works, and is expected. I resolved this before in our Windows C++ target, but Neko likes having a command-prompt (perhaps using the Windows "console" subsystem)

Alternatively, you could try using the CPP target which does not have this issue.

You can hide traces with the `no-traces` haxedef though.

Comment: It's just that with neko I could have embedded my `.swf` library and made `.exe` standalone, but with `cpp` I get `cannot grow buffer` -error when I try to embed it... Any ideas? :/

Comment: So you're using `embed="true"` like [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxeflixel/tMxay8rw7mo/4QAj443iCgAJ)? Is the `.swf` file large?

Comment: This seems to be the relevant Haxe issue, still open: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3237

Comment: well, it is 6400kb and yes `embed="true"`

Comment: so by what I am reading my swf file shouldnt cause any problems yet? Right? ... :/

Comment: Actually, it looks like that particular issue is about the Flash target, it just has a similar error message. But in principle it seems to be the same on Cpp: http://forum.haxepunk.com/index.php?topic=751.0

Comment: awh, seems pretty big & old problem... guess I can kiss goodbye to standalone `.exe` if I continue using Haxe and targeting windows... Untill someone fixes it :/